# Stative verbs with present perfect simple

Tags: present-perfect, stative-verbs

First of all,

**1.** Can I use stative verbs with the present perfect simple? For example, *know* is a stative verb, Can I say:

> **Have you known** my real name is John?

In sentence about I meant to ask, *“**Have** you **heard** about my real name?” (if yes it means you know my name) i.e. when you was born until now and if not, you can still know about that (present perfect).

I found that I must to use present tense (**Did** you **know** my real name is John?).

2. Why? (Grammatically perspective)

Comment: The first sentence would normally end with something like *all this time*, but it's still okay without that, even if slightly unusual.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use stative verbs with present perfect progressive. "I have been knowing…" is not possible. That is probably what you mean. Like Jason said "have you known" is used with duration, for example: "how long have you known my real name is John?"

Comment: I don't meant to present perfect continues/progressive I meant to simple tense. however, your answer is not fully detailed. 1) Can I use: Have you known my real name is John?, 2) you've said that Have you known... used with duration. So this sentence: He's known to be a very good violinist. is not related to duration of time but it correct. ( taken from: https://www.learnamericanenglishonline.com/Purple%20Level/P9%20Know.html)

Comment: That is a different usage of the verb. " he is known to be" means that he has the reputation of being a good violinist. Many people consider him to be a good violinist.